# method that will be called after call was ended

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to do something after i finished call which is initiated from my app

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",mynumber]]];
```

i want to perform some method after the call finished or ended , which method will called when call was ended ? :S

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible afaik. This call will terminate or suspend your app, and there is no real way of getting back to an active state.

Answer (score 1):

You can call canOpenURL to determine whether calling that URL will actually work or not.